# Appending directory to pkginclude_header

Tags: c++, makefile, autotools, autoconf, automake

Is there anyway I can modify the path for pkginclude_ without actually changing the structure of my project? Heres the directory stucture I have.

```
My_Project >
       include >
             banana.h
             apple.h
             pear.h
Makefile.am
configure
```

In the Makefile.am I have..

```
pkginclude_HEADERS=include/*.h
```

Running make install places the files in..

```
/usr/include/My_Project/
```

What I would like to happen is have includes installed in..

```
/usr/include/My_Project/fruits/
```

I would like to do this without passing any flags into configure or make and without changing the directory structure on my machine. Is there a way to specifiy this as the default behaviour?

Digging around the ineterweb. Couldn't find the answer, although I may have missed it. I rather dislike autotools docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about:

```
fruitsdir=$(pkgincludedir)/fruits
fruits_HEADERS=include/*.h
```

the more orthodox way would be to restructure your project to have the fruits/ directory:

```
My_Project > 
   includes > 
      fruits > 
         apple.h
         banana.h
         pear.h
```

and then add to My_Project/includes/Makefile.am

```
nobase_pkginclude_HEADERS = fruits/apple.h fruits/banana.h fruits/pear.h
```

Comment: Thanks. I also understand the orthodox way, just didnt want to change my dir structure at this point. Thanks for the tip and answer

Answer (score 1):

In Makefile.am:

```
pkgincludedir = $(includedir)/$(PACKAGE)/fruits
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. I solved it the way I answered below however this also works

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this method,

In Makefile.am

```
nobase_pkginclude_HEADERS=fruits/*.h
```